# Flutter Row Inside ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a `Row` inside of a list view and am getting the error

```
I/flutter (13858): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (13858): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (13858): BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
I/flutter (13858): These invalid constraints were provided to RenderParagraph's layout() function by the following
I/flutter (13858): function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
I/flutter (13858):   RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:805:17)
I/flutter (13858): The offending constraints were:
I/flutter (13858):   BoxConstraints(w=72.0, h=Infinity)
```

Following the guidance found for that error, I have tried wrapping my `ListView` in an `Expanded`, but that only leads to `Expanded widgets must be placed inside Flex widgets.`, which leads me to trying another approach.... and ending up back with this same error.

My widget is below.  Is there a way to get this working?  What I am ultimately trying to do is show multiple sets of rows with some text between between them, allowing for the user to scroll the page up and down.

```
class _RoutineEditState extends State<RoutineEdit> {
  String routineName;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit Routine'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 5),
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('ddedede'),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Set'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I am not aware of your desired layout.

Just to fix the error. we have three options.

**First:** use - `IntrinsicHeight` widget.

code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit Routine'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        //shrinkWrap: true,
        //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 5),
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('ddedede'),
          IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('Set'),
                Text('Set'),
                Text('Set'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Second:** wrap your row in `LimitedBox` and keep - `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`

code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit Routine'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 5),
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('ddedede'),
          LimitedBox(
            maxHeight: 200.0,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('Set'),
                Text('Set'),
                Text('Set'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Third:** remove or comment - `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit Routine'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 5),
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('ddedede'),
          Row(
           // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Set'),
              Text('Set'),
              Text('Set'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60432234/how-to-set-the-list-of-json-data-inside-list-in-the-listview-builder-in-flutter

Comment: what to do if there is listview as second child of row? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61012369/flutter-how-to-expand-first-child-of-row-to-listview-height-as-second-child

Answer (score 4):

`Expanded` widget must be the child of `Row` or `Column` widgets, but you have used it directly in `body` property. Try to remove the first `Expanded` widget.

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit Routine'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 5),
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('ddedede'),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Text('Set'),
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Text('Reps'),
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Text('lbs'),
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Text('prev'),
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Text('...'),
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          // Column(
          //   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          //   children: <Widget>[
          //     SizedBox(
          //       height: 24,
          //     ),
          //     TextField(
          //         controller: TextEditingController(text: routineName),
          //         keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          //         decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Name of routine')),
          //     SizedBox(
          //       height: 24,
          //     ),
          //   ],
          // ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error - I have updated and shortened the example code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the Expanded Widget. This will resolve your issue

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: YourWidget(),
    ),
  ],
)
```