# Flutter. How to expand first child of row to listview height as second child?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

My example code:

```
  Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text('text'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Title1'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Title2'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
```

[image]

How to expand first Container to Listview height? I tried IntrinsicHeight, but it do not works with listview.

Comment: does it help to add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,` in your main row?

Comment: @LonelyWolf thanks, with this parameter row will expand to full height. But I want row fit to listview height. So this don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a list controller to the list and use its position.viewportDimension property to get the height.

There, however, has to be a frame drop as you have to wait for the list item to be laid on screen before you can access the viewport dimension.

[Check this example in dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/94d1cd29715107f8bc23aa8a526f277f)

Press the + button in the example to add list items.
You can notice the frame lag there but, it works.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler way would be to change `Listview` to `Column` & wrap it with `SingleChildScrollView` then wrap Row with `IntrinsicHeight`

Code:

```
body: IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text('text'),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                //   shrinkWrap: true,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Title1'),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Title2'),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Title1'),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Title2'),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Title1'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```